# Avoiding an ambiguous match exception

Tags: c#, reflection, ambiguous-call

I am invoking a static method *Parse* on a type via reflection because I do not know the type of the object at compile-time (I do know, however, it has a *Parse* method, taking a string).

However, I am getting an ambiguous match exception, presumably because there are a lot of overloaded *Parse* methods each taking a single object (string, int, double etc.).

How can I be more specific in my method invocation to ensure I reach the correct method (*Parse(string s)*) and the exception is not thrown.

My code looks like this:

```
Type returnType = p.PropertyType;
object value = returnType.GetMethod("Parse").Invoke(null, new string[] { "1" });
```

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx) overload and use

```
returnType.GetMethod("Parse", new [] {typeof(string)})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, guys.  To save the next guy some trouble, for reference types, use something like this:
    typeof(string).MakeByRefType();

Comment: @Bitterblue What, you don't like type inference? I actually prefer it the way Benjamin formatted it. I prefer type inference (it's cleaner) than explicit typing. His answer is good, style shouldn't play a factor in the quality of an answer. The result of the answer is the only outcome that matters.

Comment: @Bitterblue I'm not 'young' and that sure sounds condescending. A programmer that cannot read ```new [] { typeof(string) }``` has other issues than maintaining code. The type is literally right there. Plus 'crazy one-liners' aren't relevant, your preferred style just adds redundant letters into this very line. I'd argue that ```new Type[] {...}``` is less readable, because the line's longer and that's irrelevant information/boilerplate/noise. Hence: It's a matter of style and you started the discussion with a passive aggressive 'would have upvoted, if it would cater to my taste'..

Comment: @Bitterblue Get some experience? I've been in my career for 9 years, almost a decade. I have plenty already (and plenty more to learn), but I know enough that verbosity is a terrible way to grade an answer.

Comment: Be careful, it will not work if 2 methods have the same names, same number of parameters and same types of parameters. I'm thinking here of explicit cast operators overloads. For example `public static explicit double(MyType obj)` and `public static explicit float(MyType obj)`. You will still have an `AmbiguousMatchException`. In this case, you could use `returnType.GetMethods().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == "op_Explicit" && m.ReturnType == typeof(float))` for example.