# Store Generic Type Parameter for Further Use

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

Is there any way to store Generic Type Parameter for further use .
Scenario is something like that .

```
Queue<ApiHandlerHelper> requestQueue = new Queue<ApiHandlerHelper> ();

public void HitApi<T> (ApiHandlerHelper helper)
    {
        if (_IfHandlerProcessing) {
            requestQueue.Enqueue (helper);
        } else {
            StartCoroutine (checkInternetConnection<T> ());
            _IfHandlerProcessing = true;
        }
    }
```

HitApi receives call from multiple managers , i want to check if Hitpi is busy processing request of one manager the the upcoming request shall go inside queue . Now i need to store Generic type parameter "T" to be used on later stage. something like this

```
AoiHandlerObject.StoreGenerticType<T> ();
```

I need to store T type , so that HitApi can be called automatically when we receive response for previous manager .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store a generic type parameter, but you can do it for *generic arguments*. While you won't be able to provide a generic argument type during compile-time, using reflection you can call a generic method (or instantiate a generic type):

```
Type genericArg1 = typeof(T);
```

Now your method should be called using reflection:

```
// obj.HitApi<T>(ApiHandlerHelper helper)
typeof(ClassContainingHitApiMethod)
      .GetMethod("HitApi", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .MakeGenericMethod(genericArg1)
      .Invoke(instanceOfClassContainingHitApiMethod, new object[] { instanceOfApiHelper });
```

Comment: So you are saying Reflection (this solution) is not applicable where T represents a Class which does not implement any interface/ inherit any class ?

Comment: Can you please explain the above mentioned Signature . I have idea of Reflection and how to do this in JAVA . It doesn't look much different still want to make sure i am thinking it straight.

Comment: @ArunPandey No, I mean you need to force a `T` parameter to implement or derive something, because `T` "as is" given as generic argument to a reflection call will prevent you from casting `object` to something more concrete to access members during compile-time, or you'll be forced to implement everything using reflection, which isn't enjoyable at all

Comment: @ArunPandey Sorry, nevermind. I missed that your method returns `void`. I've dropped that part from my answer. Check the updated answer.

Comment: . So it seems to be working fine for me just a bit of problem . I have overloaded HitApi method , so while using Reflection it gives me AmbiguousMatchException .Both methods accept different parameters and number is also different. I also experimented with new object[] { parameters }  but it always gives me exception . Any idea , what could be the issue.

Comment: @ArunPandey This seems to be a different issue than your original quesiton... Check this other Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969411/avoiding-an-ambiguous-match-exception

Comment: Anyways , i am selecting it as a solution . As it's quite appropriate for the kind of issue i was facing . Thanks @Martías , much appreciated.

Comment: @ArunPandey no problem, I'm glad this answers has been useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof(T)` to retrieve the [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance representing the type passed to the `T` parameter. You can then store this `Type` instance for further use like any other object reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store an instance of type `Type`, storing the type of `T`, then you can use `typeof(T)`.

```
var type = typeof(T);
StoreType(type);
```

But getting `HitApi<T>` from a *variable* `T` can be troublesome, as it requires some reflection. I think it might actually be *less* work to store `typeof(HitApi<T>)` instead, depending on what your exact needs are.