# ambiguous match when calling method via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

When I try to call `JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject` via reflection I get an `AmbiguousMatchException` despite me specifying the type of the parameter for the overload I want to call

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetMethod("DeserializeObject", new[] { typeof(string) });
```

Not sure what other info I can supply so that it finds a unique match

any ideas?

Comment: You could try getting all methods with `GetMethods()` and then filter them with LINQs `Single()` or `Where()`.

Comment: cos there is a generic overload too? Do GetMethods and see what it returns

Comment: @thehennyy is right, there are several methods with the same name, but different parameters, so thats why you get the exception

Comment: I think you need to create your own `Binder` subclass and use that to select between the generic and non-generic overloads.

Comment: yes, I realize there is more than one match. I'd like to know how to specify a criteria that gets a unique match. there is a generic method and non generic method which both take a single string parameter - how do you distinguish between them?

Comment: yes - I've called GetMethods and can see the two mehods that have the same signature - just not sure how to select the one I want (the generic one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding an ambiguous match exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969411/avoiding-an-ambiguous-match-exception)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use the `GetMethods()` method with Linqs `Single()` method to find the MethodInfo you are looking for:

```
var method = typeof (JsonConvert).GetMethods().Single(
            m =>
                m.Name == "DeserializeObject" &&
                m.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 &&
                m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(string));
```