# GetType("UnityEngine.Debug").GetMethod("Log", new Type[] { typeof(string) }); generates errors in Immediate mode panel, not in code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

Edited: Turns out the errors I reported below in my original question only occur when executing this statement in the Visual Studio Immediate mode panel when stopped in the debugger.

```
type.GetMethod("Log", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
```

When executed in the program itself the statement returns the method I am looking for and I am able to use it as a delegate.

My revised question is: Why does executing this in the Debugger Immediate mode panel generate an error? Is there a way to execute this statement in the debugger Immediate mode panel without an error?

---- original question below ----

Am writing some code that will both run in Unity3D and separately and have a custom logger that should delegate to [Unity3D Debug.Log()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) when running in Unity.

Unity lists two method signatures for Debug.Log:

```
 public static void Log(object message);
 public static void Log(object message, Object context);
```

I am able to get the type UnityEngine.Debug using reflection:

```
Type type = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("UnityEngine.CoreModule").
    GetType("UnityEngine.Debug");
```

However I'm not able to successfully get the Log method using GetMethod().

I can see the two Log method signatures listed using GetMethods(). I'm looking to get the first one: [11]: {Void Log(System.Object)}

```
> type.GetMethods();
{System.Reflection.MethodInfo[47]}
  [0]: {UnityEngine.ILogger get_unityLogger()}
  [1]: {Void DrawLine(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Color, Single)}
  [2]: {Void DrawLine(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Color)}
  [3]: {Void DrawLine(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)}
  [4]: {Void DrawLine(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Color, Single, Boolean)}
  [5]: {Void DrawRay(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Color, Single)}
  [6]: {Void DrawRay(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Color)}
  [7]: {Void DrawRay(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)}
  [8]: {Void DrawRay(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Color, Single, Boolean)}
  [9]: {Void Break()}
  [10]: {Void DebugBreak()}
  [11]: {Void Log(System.Object)}
  [12]: {Void Log(System.Object, UnityEngine.Object)}
  ...
```

Taking a look at the answers to a similar question here [Avoiding an ambiguous match exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969411/avoiding-an-ambiguous-match-exception) here's what I've tried:

```
> type.GetMethod("Log");
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.

> type.GetMethod("Log", new Type[] { typeof(System.Object) });
Method `CreateInstance' not found in type `System.Array'.

> type.GetMethod("Log", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
Method `CreateInstance' not found in type `System.Array'.
```

Comment: This exception seems to be raised not by the `GetMethod` method itself, but somewhere deeper. Can you please provide the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Thanks for asking that question dymanoid. The errors I reported above were generated when paused at a breakpoint and entering statements in the Immediate mode panel in Visual Studio. When I executed type.GetMethod("Log", new Type[] { typeof(string) }); in the program code it ran without error. I'm curious why the statements didn't work in the Immediate mode panel. Understanding better when errors executing statements in immediate don't reflect what would happen during program execution will make my debugging more efficient. I'll modify the question to reflect that.

Comment: See revised question. I'd like to understand when to discount errors reported when running a statement in the debuggers immediate mode panel to make my debugging more efficient.