# How do I use reflection to call a non public method with 0 arguments?

Tags: c#, reflection

My class has two methods that look like this:

```
void Update()
void Update(string)
```

With reflection, I want to call the top one, but when I try this:

```
            const BindingFlags findFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

            var methodInfo = script.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, findFlags);
```

I get a `AmbiguousMatchException`.  How do I call the no arg method?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___ - see the documentation for the `types` parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding an ambiguous match exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969411/avoiding-an-ambiguous-match-exception)

Comment: @JimG. I don't know if it answers the question. It's not the same answer. I haven't used C# in years so I don't have a convenient way to check.

Comment: Which languages are you using these days?

Comment: @JimG. Lately? TypeScript. Before that, Java + Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
            var methodInfo = script.GetType().GetMethod("Update", findFlags, null, new Type[] { }, null);
```