# System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to get the `MethodInfo` from a method `TableExists<T>` so I can call it with a type.

The method is declared inside `OrmLiteSchemaApi` class.  There are 2 overloads:

```
public static bool TableExists<T>(this IDbConnection dbConn)
{
  // code omitted
}

public static bool TableExists(this IDbConnection dbConn, string tableName, string schema = null)
{
  // code omitted
}
```

I am trying to get the `MethodInfo` like this:

```
var tableMethod = typeof(OrmLiteSchemaApi).GetMethod("TableExists");
```

But it generates exception:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: 'Ambiguous match found.'

I could only find an old question related to this that suggested to pass an empty object array as parameter but this doesn't seem to work for .net core.

I guess I need to specify the specific overload but I am not sure exactly how.

How do I get the `MethodInfo`?

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to get the first overload? You'll need to pass the parameter type for that (the fact that it's an extension method doesn't change the fact that the first parameter is of type `IDbConnection`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding an ambiguous match exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969411/avoiding-an-ambiguous-match-exception)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`GetMethods`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=netcore-2.2) (plural!) to get an array of all matching methods, and then look for the one which has [`IsGenericMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.isgenericmethod?view=netframework-3.5&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.2):

```
var tm = typeof(OrmLiteSchemaApi)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "TableExists")
        .Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod);
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

I recommend this over using parameter specifiers, since it'll give you an object you can step through at debug time if there are ever any problems.

Answer (score 7):

Passing an empty object array would only work if you're looking for a function with no parameters.  Instead, you need to use a [different overload of GetMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___) that specifies the types of parameters as a type array.  That way you can tell it which reference to get by specifying which types of parameters it should look for.

Comment: `GetMethod(string)` will return a method with parameters. The exception isn't thrown because the method has parameters, but because there are two methods with that name. But the solution is still the same.

Comment: @ScottHannen, correct.  I was referring to the OP's attempted solution to pass an empty object array.  That would not return the correct value, since the method being searched for has a parameter.