# How to call the overloaded method using reflection in c#. AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: c#, reflection

I try to call overloaded method using reflection.

```
public void SomeMethod(string param)
{
    param = param.Length > 0 ? param : null;
    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("methodName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    theMethod.Invoke(this, param);
}
```

When I use one of both method all works well:

```
//works well if param = "" (null)
private void methodName(){
}

//works well if param = "anystring"
private void methodName(string parameter){
}
```

I can use only one of those methods. But when I use both methods in the class (I need to use both cases - when param will be passed and without him) I get the exception:

> AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found

How to can I use both overloaded methods?

Comment: If you haven't tried yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083067/system-reflection-ambiguousmatchexception-ambiguous-match-found

Comment: if i understand, you want this :If ``param`` != null And not empty ==> call method with parameters, else ==> call method without parameters?

Comment: @Sajid yes I will. And I need to use both of these methods

Comment: @JibяaᴎKhaᴎ unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=netframework-1.1#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_System_Reflection_Binder_System_Type___System_Reflection_ParameterModifier___) overload of the method `GetMethod` to find appropriate method `methodName`. This overload takes to account number of method arguments and its types. Using this overload method `SomeMethod` should be rewritten like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(string param)
{
    Type thisType = GetType();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
    {
        // Find and invoke method with one argument.
        MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("methodName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] {typeof(string)}, null);
        theMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] {param});
    }
    else
    {
        // Find and invoke method without arguments.
        MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("methodName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[0], null);
        theMethod.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample of using this approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/efK1nt.

Comment: You need to understand. I exactly that execute in my code, All works well. But not when I use both methods

Comment: this will call the same method(*method with parameters*)

Comment: @Sajid Here is a sample that shows that this method distincts method with parameter and without it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/REZvXx.

Comment: @Valentyn Hruzytskyi Yes, I understand it. When you use only one method `methodName` method `GetMethod` can find it only by its name and binding flags. But when you use both methods in one class method `GetMethod` cannot find single method only using method name and binding flags, because both of this methods satisfy search crieria. Therefore additional parameters (types and number of arguments) are needed to find a single method.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev, Sorry, i see, you change the ``Type[]``.Note that ``param.Length`` throw an exception if ``param`` is ``null``

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw the difference. It helped!

Comment: @Sajid You are right. I'll change `param.Length` to `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can test on parameters number of **methodName**, if is equal or greater than *0*, like the following code :

```
public void SomeMethod(string param)
{
    Type thisType = this.GetType();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param))
    {
        MethodInfo theMethod1 = thisType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "methodName" && m.GetParameters().Count() > 0);

        theMethod1.Invoke(this, new[] { param });
    }
    else
    {
        MethodInfo theMethod2 = thisType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "methodName" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 0);

        theMethod2.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you fix the issue

Comment: @Valentyn Hruzytskyi , if i understand correctly, you want a method like this?