# C# Using dynamic lambda but getting an ambiguous match when selecting a method to use

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, ambiguous-call

I have the following static method for selecting between filter options as per a blog post by Pashov.

```
public static class ExpressionRetriever  
    {  
        private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");  
        private static MethodInfo startsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });  
        private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });



    public static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, ExpressionFilter filter)  
    {  
        MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.PropertyName);  
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);  
        switch (filter.Comparison)  
        {  
            case Comparison.Equal:  
                return Expression.Equal(member, constant);  
            case Comparison.GreaterThan:  
                return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);  
            case Comparison.GreaterThanOrEqual:  
                return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);  
            case Comparison.LessThan:  
                return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);  
            case Comparison.LessThanOrEqual:  
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);  
            case Comparison.NotEqual:  
                return Expression.NotEqual(member, constant);  
            case Comparison.Contains:  
                return Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, constant);  
            case Comparison.StartsWith:  
                return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);  
            case Comparison.EndsWith:  
                return Expression.Call(member, endsWithMethod, constant);  
            default:  
                return null;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Once it hits the line `return Expression.Call(member, startsWithMethod, constant);` it throws the following error:

```
> System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'ExpressionRetriever' threw an exception.
  Source=JobsLedger.API
  StackTrace:
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Shared.OrderAndFIlterHelpers.DynamicFilteringHelper.ExpressionRetriever.GetExpression[T](ParameterExpression param, ExpressionFilter filter) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\Shared\OrderAndFIlterHelpers\DynamicFilteringHelper.cs:line 84
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Shared.OrderAndFIlterHelpers.DynamicFilteringHelper.ConstructAndExpressionTree[T](List`1 filters) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\Shared\OrderAndFIlterHelpers\DynamicFilteringHelper.cs:line 39
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.Shared.ODataFilterAndSort.ParginatedFilteredSorted[T](IQueryable`1 source, String query) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\Shared\OrderAndFIlterHelpers\ODataFilterAndSort.cs:line 41
   at JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.API.App.ClientServices.ClientServices.GetPaginatedClients(String query) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\ControllerServices\API\App\ClientServices\ClientServices.cs:line 65
   at JobsLedger.API.Controllers.API.App.ClientController.Index(String query) in C:\AURELIA\1.0 - JobsLedgerSPA -ASPNET CORE 3.0\JobsLedger.API\Controllers\API\App\ClientController.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> 
> Inner Exception 1: AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
```

If I comment out the `private static MethodInfo containsMethod` and `private static MethodInfo endsWithMethod` It now works.

I found this [post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969419/5750758) (same kind of problem) that said to use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Type___) overload but its already doing that.

How can I avoid this so that it can select between the different methods without seeing ambiguous choices?

Comment: Can you provide a copy/paste ready minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your question didn't say so specifically, it was inferred from the provided stack trace that you are running the code in the .NET Core environment.

Note that it was not possible to **reproduce** this error on the .NET Framework environment.

When testing in .Net Core the error was occurring on this line

```
private static MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
```

Note the lack of an argument type to narrow the method match.

By providing an argument type like

```
private static MethodInfo containsMethod = 
    typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[]{typeof (string)});
```

The error was resolved and the code behaved as expected.

### [.Net Fiddle of working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/smbY3V)